# Project Reactor and Safe Publication

Tags: multithreading, spring-webflux, project-reactor, java-memory-model, safe-publication

I need your help. There is a reactive chain in a Spring WebFlux application that uses R2dbcRepository:

```java
entityRepository //0
    .findById(entityId) //1 Mono<Entity>
    .doOnNext(e-> e.setValue("0")) //2
    .flatMap(entity-> //3
        entityRepository //4
            .save(entity) //5 Mono<Entity>
            .flatMap(this::process) //6 Mono<Result>
            .flatMap(result-> { //7
                entity.setValue("1"); //8
                return entityRepository //9
                    .save(entity) //10 Mono<Entity>
                    .thenReturn(result); //11 Mono<Result>
            }) //12
            .flatMap(result-> /*REST request using WebFlux*/) //13 Mono<Body>
            .flatMap(body -> { //14
                entity.setValue("2"); //15
                return entityRepository //16
                    .save(entity) //17 Mono<Entity>
                    .thenReturn(body); //18 Mono<Body>
            }) //19
            
    ); //20 Mono<Body>
```

On line 3, there is an "entity" object that is modified later on lines 8 and 15 (probably in a different threads). Is this an unsafe publication of the "entity" object between different threads in reactive stream? Is this approach to writing a reactive chain incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it appears that there are no concurrent (simultaneous) changes to the entity, and all processing is completed in a sequential manner, so it should work safely. It's important to remember to include the `volatile` keyword in the value field if it's being accessed for both reading and writing in multiple threads.

However, I strongly recommend creating an immutable entity as it is a more dependable and error-free approach. If you plan on utilizing this entity instance in a wide scope (across various classes/modules within your application), it's better to use an immutable entity for safety purposes. The use of a mutable entity can lead to unpredictable consistency problems as your application progresses. Therefore, it's best to use mutable entities only in limited and highly encapsulated scopes.